# How to make depth buffer work for sub scene in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, javafx-3d

I've created sub scene to display 3D objects and I've got some issue with depth buffer presented below.

[image]

Spheres are same size of course.

In fxml file I've got

```
<SubScene fx:id="subScene" depthBuffer="true">
```

and `subScene.isDepthBuffer()` returns true.

I event tried creating SubScene with

```
subScene = new SubScene(root, 800, 800, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
pane.getChildren().set(0, subScene);
```

with no luck.

Would be grateful for any help. I also would like to know is it just some JavaFX bug or I'm doing, or understanding, something wrongly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem.
Depth buffer didn't work because I had

```
camera.setNearClip(Double.MIN_VALUE);
```

which was not my best idea. Changing it to

```
camera.setNearClip(0.01);
```

solved the issue.